# Сумма элементов массива в jsp

Tags: java, массивы, jsp

Помогите разобраться с jsp.
Страница получает массив, я могу его распечатать в цикле:

```
<c:forEach var="el" items="${currentStatement.marks}">
    <li>
        <p><c:out value="${el}" /></p>
    </li>
</c:forEach>
```

Но как посчитать сумму этого массива?
Пробую Scriplet, но такой фокус не проходит:

```
        <% int sum = 0;
           for (int i = 0; i < ${currentStatement.marks}.length; i++) {
              sum = sum + ${currentStatement.marks}[i];
           }
           out.println(sum);
        %>
```

Scriplet не понимает такой переменной, как и просто `currentStatement.marks`.

Так как передать массив в Scriplet? Или, может, есть способ посчитать без него?

Comment: А как вы передаёте массив: в `request` или `session`?

Comment: request


(нужно ещё символов)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я не ошибаюсь, синтаксис знака доллара и фигурных скобок, то есть, `${}`, работает только в контексте тегов. Как, например, вы используете эту запись в `c:forEach` и в `c:out`.

Если же вы хотите обратиться к какому-то атрибуту в скриптлетах JSP-страниц, то тогда его нужно получать посредством обращения к тому объекту (request, session, context), в котором он хранится.

Любая JSP-страница имеет несколько неявных объектов, к которым мы можем запросто обращаться, пользуясь тем, что в конечном итоге JSP-страница - это обычный сервлет. Объект `request` - один из таких неявных объектов.

Вы сказали, что помещаете массив в `request` - тогда получить его оттуда в скриптлете можно следующим образом:

```
request.getAttribute("currentStatement.marks");
```

Правда, тип возвращаемого значения метода `getAttribute()` - это `Object`, поэтому нужно будет сделать соответствующее приведение типа. И далее уже можно будет работать с полученным массивом.

Единственное что, я не знаю, точка в данном случае - это часть имени, или это обращение к полю объекта. Если первое, то подходит вариант выше. Если второе - то тогда получаете объект как

```
request.getAttribute("currentStatement");
```

приводя тип, а затем получаете от данного объекта его поле-массив.